# Meeting maximum guests(time-interval) in k attempts

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, intervals

There is party going on , the time interval of each guest in party is given. I can go into party room k times . Now I should pick  k time instances so that I'll meet maximum guests

n - no. of guests
k - no. of attempts

Ex: for n=5 & k=2

given intervals of 5 guests [1,3] [4,8] [1,5] [6,8] [4,8] 
At time=1 I can meet 1st & 3rd guest & at time=6 I can meet 2nd ,4th & 5th guest .So I can meet maximum of 5 guests in 2 attempt .
My failed approaches :

1. Used interval tree to find Point of Maximum overlaps , deleted intervals at that point & did same second time.  It fails because it gives just the point of maximum guest , like I got time=4 in this example. Which is bad choice because then I can meet only 4 guests.  (3 at time=4 & 1 at time=1 or time=6)
   So I'm thinking it is Dynamic programming & Now I'm struck .
   Give or suggest me an algorithm or solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I would suggest going for Dynamic programming. You can easily check that "the best time" to go into party room is time when someone's time is up. In your example it would be 3,5 and 8. Then what you want to do is calculate the best possible scenario of taking 2 from it(i am still solving it on your example as I think it would be the best explanation). And here you can calculate what would be if you would take 3, then 5, then 8 and calculate for them using the same recursion. You can keep taken times in set to avoid duplicates and after you have finished your k-steps just check its size and the biggest one is the solution.

Comment: Thank you, the fact that "best time" is when someone's time is up, helping me lot. . Now I'm working on it, the complexity is C(e,k) . e-end point set & k-no. Of attempts.  Any further help appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the help bro, It's a combination of interval overlap & dynamic programming. I implemented your solution & for searching intervals belonging to endpoint I used interval tree reducing O(n) to lon(n).

Answer (score 0):

Build list of time points when anybody comes in (or similar points when anybody leaves the room, like @Ajris advised). Here times are 1,4,6

Build a graph (it is bipartite directed for this moment), the left part contains guests, the right part contains time points. For every guest make edges to time points when he was in the room. Here edges are:

```
 g1: t1
 g2: t4, t6
 g3  t1, t4
 g4: t6
 g5: t4 ,t6
```

Now add auxiliary vertex S'  left to guests and add edges with unit capacity to all guests (graph is not more bipartite, just directed). Add one more vertex S (source) left to S' and make edge S-S' with capacity K

Also add target vertex T right to times and add edges from every time point (with capacity K).

Now solve maximum integer flow problem for S-T source-sink pair with [any available algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem)